# Is there any way to working with only one array with jQuery.each()?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a project where I filter the elements by clicking on the checkbox. I think biggest problem is with **jQuery.each()** function. You can see code below what it does. I need to create only **one** array and filter values only in this array, because now, i am getting duplicates. Is there any way how to fix this with **jQuery.each()** or i need to use another function? I know how this problem arises, but I didn't find a solution.

Of course, data for every checkbox are mixed. For example, some data fall under all checkboxes, another data only to one checkbox etc. You can see **get_filter function.**

```
filter_data();


function filter_data()
{
    $('.filter_data').html('<div id="loading" style="" ></div>');
    var action = 'fetch_data';

    var brand = get_filter('brand');
    var jackpot = get_filter('jackpot');
    var volatility = get_filter('volatility');
    var special_features = get_filter('special_features');

    $.ajax({
        url:"fetch_data.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{action:action, brand:brand, jackpot:jackpot, volatility:volatility, special_features:special_features},
        success:function(data){
            $('.filter_data').html(data);
        }
    });
}

function get_filter(class_name)
{
    var filter = [];
    $('.'+class_name+':checked').each(function(){
        filter.push($(this).val());

        console.log(filter);

    });
    return filter;
}

$('.common_selector').click(function(){
    filter_data();
});
```

**fetch_data.php**

```
<?php

//fetch_data.php
include 'template.php';
$pdo = pdo_connect_mysql();


if(isset($_POST["action"]))
{

    $query = ('SELECT * FROM slotselect.slot WHERE 1');

    $query2 = ('SELECT * FROM slotselect.slot, slotselect.slot_features, slotselect.special_features WHERE slot_features.id_slot = slot.id_slot AND slot_features.id_sf = special_features.id_sf');


    if(isset($_POST["special_features"]))
    {
        $sf_filter = implode("','", $_POST["special_features"]);
        $query .= " AND special_features.id_sf IN('".$sf_filter."') ";
        $query2 .= " AND special_features.id_sf IN('".$sf_filter."') ";

    }

    if(isset($_POST["brand"]))
    {
        $brand_filter = implode("','", $_POST["brand"]);
        $query .= " AND id_provider IN('".$brand_filter."') ";
        $query2 .= " AND id_provider IN('".$brand_filter."') ";
    }

    if(isset($_POST["jackpot"]))
    {
        $jackpot_filter = implode("','", $_POST["jackpot"]);
        $query .= " AND id_jackpot IN('".$jackpot_filter."') ";
        $query2 .= " AND id_jackpot IN('".$jackpot_filter."') ";

    }

    if(isset($_POST["volatility"]))
    {
        $volatility_filter = implode("','", $_POST["volatility"]);
        $query .= " AND id_vol IN('".$volatility_filter."') ";
        $query2 .= " AND id_vol IN('".$volatility_filter."') ";
    }




    $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    $total_row = $statement->rowCount();
    $output = '';



    if(isset($_POST["special_features"]))
    {

        $statement = $pdo->prepare($query2);
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
        $total_row = $statement->rowCount();
        $output = '';

        if($total_row > 0)
        {
            foreach($result as $row)
            {


                $pom= $row['id_provider'];
                $pom2= $row['id_slot'];


                $provi = $pdo->prepare('SELECT logo FROM slotselect.provider WHERE id_provider = ?');
                $provi->execute([$pom]);
                $provik = $provi->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                $name = $pdo->prepare('SELECT name FROM slotselect.slot WHERE id_slot = ?');
                $name->execute([$pom2]);
                $namee = $name->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);





                $output .= '


                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 wow bounceInUp" data-wow-duration="1.4s" id="services">
                        <div class="box">
                          <div class="logo pasik">
                            <img src="admin/uploads/'. $provik['logo']. '" width="80" height="60">
                          </div>

                          <img src="admin/uploads/'. $row['image'] . '" width="100%" height="150">
                          <p></p>
                          <h4 class="title"><a href="">'.$namee['name'].'</a></h4>
                          <p></p>
                          <a href="slot.php?id='.$row['id_slot'].'" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
                          <p></p>
                        </div>
                      </div>';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $output = '<h3>No Data Found</h3>';
        }
        echo $output;
    }






    if($total_row > 0)
    {
        foreach($result as $row)
        {


            $pom= $row['id_provider'];
            $pom2= $row['id_slot'];


            $provi = $pdo->prepare('SELECT logo FROM slotselect.provider WHERE id_provider = ?');
            $provi->execute([$pom]);
            $provik = $provi->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $name = $pdo->prepare('SELECT name FROM slotselect.slot WHERE id_slot = ?');
            $name->execute([$pom2]);
            $namee = $name->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);





            $output .= '


            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 wow bounceInUp" data-wow-duration="1.4s" id="services">
                <div class="box">
                  <div class="logo pasik">
                    <img src="admin/uploads/'. $provik['logo']. '" width="80" height="60">
                  </div>

                  <img src="admin/uploads/'. $row['image'] . '" width="100%" height="150">
                  <p></p>
                  <h4 class="title"><a href="">'. $namee['name']. '</a></h4>
                  <p></p>
                  <a href="slot.php?id='. $row['id_slot']. '" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
                  <p></p>
                </div>
              </div>


   ';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $output = '<h3>No Data Found</h3>';
    }
    echo $output;
}



?>
```

Some examples:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mx7WG.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG9YY.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiZMx.jpg

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: I suspect the problem is in the `fetch_data.php` code, not the code in the question.

Comment: I added the code from `fetch_data.php`

Comment: i have looked @ the image and logic. i don't see any issues. actually it's not duplicate. your print array in each() function which print correctly. first time it will have one check box value and next time it will have two check box value and so on

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to transmit one Array with all the ID's to your fetch_data.php you coud rewrite your js-code like this:

```
var filter_array = [
    'brand',
    'jackpot',
    'volatility',
    'special_features'
];

filter_data(filter_array);

function filter_data(filter_array)
{
    $('.filter_data').html('<div id="loading" style="" ></div>');
    var action = 'fetch_data';

    var selected_filters = get_filter(filter_array);

    console.log(selected_filters);

    $.ajax({
        url:"fetch_data.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{action:action, filters:selected_filters}, //selected_filters Structure = [brand:'brand_value',jackpot:'jackpot_value', ... ]
        success:function(data){
            $('.filter_data').html(data);
        }
    });
}

function get_filter(filter_array, filter = []){

    if (filter_array === undefined || filter_array.length == 0) { //check if array exists or if there are filters left to add
        var class_name = filter_array.shift(); //Removes and returns first element of filter_array

        $('.'+class_name+':checked').each(function(){
            filter[class_name] = $(this).val();
            get_filter(filter_array,filter); //called recursivly as long as there are filters to add
        });

    }
    else{
        return filter;
    }
}

$('.common_selector').click(function(){
    filter_data();
});
```

This might not use jquery.each() but it will produce an array with all the checked boxes names and values which you can iterate in you php by using foreach like this:

```
foreach($_POST['filters'] as $key => $value){
  //$key = the name of the checkbox selector | $value = the value of the associated checkbox
}
```

This code is **NOT TESTET**, but i still hope it helps.